# Create on Android a GSON from any Container like List

Tags: android, json, performance, gson

I have a `java.util.List<Student>;` whereas Student is a simple class with few attributes like `String name`, `String forName`, `int id`, `double averageCredtis`;

As in this code:

```
class Student {
  private String foreName;
  private String surName;
  private int id;
  private double averageCredits;

  public Student(String f, String n, int id, double aCred)
  {
    this.foreName = f;
    this.surName = n;
    this.id = id;
    this. averageCredits = aCred;
  }
}
```

Then I create multiple objects during runtime:

```
Student a = new Student("Alice", "Aaa", 123, 1.6);
Student b = new Student("Bob", "Bbb", 223, 1.0);
Student c = new Student("Chris", "Ccc", 457, 3.6);
```

I used to store them in a Lisdt by means of `myList.add(a);`.

I would like to generate a GSON String like:

> {   "GlobalVal": "Value",
>       "GlobalNumber": "234",
>       "Student": {"Surname": "Aaa","Forename": "Alice", "id": 123, >"averageCredit": 1.7   }
>       "Student": {"Surname": "Bbb","Forename": "Bob", "id": >223,"averageCredit": 1.0   }
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class named `Container`

```
class Container{
    String globalVal;
    int globalInt;
    List<Student> students;
}
```

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert this to JSON. Create an instance of the above class and store the values.

```
Container obj = new Container();
Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib to achieve the same.

Below link answers you question precisely.
Refer : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/